# C# technique for generating anonymous delegates that share same closure variable

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-methods

I have a situation where I need to generate a few similar anonymous delegates.  Here's an example:

```
public void Foo(AnotherType theObj)
{
    var shared = (SomeType)null;

    theObj.LoadThing += () =>
    {
        if(shared == null)
            shared = LoadShared();

        return shared.Thing;
    };

    theObj.LoadOtherThing += () =>
    {
        if(shared == null)
            shared = LoadShared();

        return shared.OtherThing;
    };

    // more event handlers here...
}
```

The trouble I'm having is that my code isn't very DRY.  The contents of each of the event handlers is EXTREMELY similar, and could be easily parameterized into a factory method.  The only thing preventing me from doing that is that each delegate needs to share the reference to the `shared` variable.  I can't pass `shared` to a factory method with the `ref` keyword, as [you can't create a closure around a `ref` varaiable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Any ideas?

Comment: You're returning something from even handlers? I think that's a really unusual thing to do, especially you can add more handlers to one event, and only the value of the last one will be used. Maybe a delegate property would be more suitable for you?

Comment: A delegate property can be invoked outside the class, which isn't what I want.  The `event` semantics, where anyone can attach, but only the class can invoke, is what I need in this case.

Comment: I think a write-only delegate property fits better. Although it's still quite weird.

Comment: I'd call a write-only property even stranger than an `event` that returns a value.  A "setter" method would be much more idiomatic than a write-only property in C#, IMO.

With the event model, you've got the option to, say, unhook the previous handler on attach, for instance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no problem that can't be solved by adding more abstraction. (*)

The pattern you are repeating over and over again is the "lazy loading" pattern. That pattern is highly amenable to being captured in a type, and in fact, it has been, in version 4 of the framework. Documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

You could then do something like:

```
public void Foo(AnotherType theObj)
{
    var shared = new Lazy<SomeType>(()=>LoadShared());
    theObj.LoadThing += () => shared.Value.Thing;
    theObj.LoadOtherThing += () => shared.Value.OtherThing;
    // more event handlers here...
}
```

And there you go. The first time `shared.Value` is accessed the value gets loaded; every subsequent time the cached value is used. Extra bonus: this is even threadsafe should the shared value be accessed on multiple threads. (See the documentation for details about precisely what guarantees we make regarding thread safety.)

---

(*) Except of course for the problem "I have too much abstraction."

Comment: Nice.. didn't know about Lazy!

Comment: Spectacular!  TIL about the `Lazy` class.

Comment: @phoog: The abstraction you need to solve the halting problem is traditionally called an "oracle". The problem is that oracles cannot be implemented using any craft we now possess.

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra layer of indirection.  Create a class that is just a wrapper for the data that you want to keep:

```
public class MyPointer<T>
{
  public T Value{get;set;}
}
```

New up a `MyPointer<SomeType>` at the start of the method and pass it into the factory.  Now the `MyPointer` reference is copied by value, so you can't change the `MyPointer` instance, but you can change the `Value` in each of the factory methods and it is reflected elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public void Foo(AnotherType theObj)
{
    var shared = (SomeType)null;

    Action handler = () =>
    {
        if(shared == null)
            shared = LoadShared();

        return Shared.Thing;
    };

    theObj.LoadThing += handler;
    theObj.LoadOtherThing += handler;

    // more event handlers here...
}
```

You can also put the Action in a method and pass a parameter:

```
public void Foo(AnotherType theObj)
{
    var shared = (SomeType)null;

    theObj.LoadThing += () => Handle("LoadThing");
    theObj.LoadOtherThing += () => Handle("LoadOtherThing");

    // more event handlers here...
}

private T Handle<T>(T returnParameter)
{
    if(shared == null)
        shared = LoadShared();

    return returnParameter;
}
```

Comment: That returns `Shared.Thing` for both handlers.

Comment: Changed the second example to reflect that

Comment: I still don't think that works.  `T` is always `string`, and `returnParameter` is just `"LoadThing"` and `"LoadOtherThing"`, respectively, not a property from `shared`.

Comment: You are right. It only works if the return type is not a property of shared!

Answer (score 1):

I like Eric's method better, but here's another approach borne out of some kind of lisp fueled delirium I think.

```
var LoaderMaker = (Func<SomeType, int> thingGetter) => {
    return () => {
        if(shared == null) shared = LoadShared();
        return thingGetter(shared);
    };
};

theObj.LoadThing = LoaderMaker(t => t.Thing);
theObj.LoadOtherThing = LoaderMaker(t => t.OtherThing);
```

Comment: The problem here is: what if Thing and OtherThing are not integers?

Comment: You replace `int` with whatever type they actually are.

Comment: and if one is an int and the other is a string?

Comment: Oh good point.  Somehow I assumed they had to be the same.  `dynamic`? :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting the repetitive code in a separate function.

```
public void Foo(AnotherType theObj)
{
    var shared = (SomeType)null;

    Func<SomeType> getShared = () =>
    {
        if(shared == null)
            shared = LoadShared();
        return shared;
    };

    // Or more compact
    Func<SomeType> getShared = () => shared ?? (shared = LoadShared());

    theObj.LoadThing += () => getShared().Thing;

    theObj.LoadOtherThing += () => getShared().OtherThing;

    // more event handlers here...
}
```